# How to play sounds in python via a def

Tags: python

I have a mini-program that can read text files and turn simple phrases into python code, it has Lexer, Parser, everything, I managed to make it play sound using "winsound" but for some reason, it plays the sound as long as the function does not return, this specific part in the code looks like this:

```
          winsound.PlaySound(self.master.files.get(args[1]), winsound.SND_ASYNC | winsound.SND_LOOP | winsound.SND_NODEFAULT)
          time.sleep(10)
          return True
```

I used the time.sleep(10) just to experiment when the sound didn't play, and what I noticed is that it plays UNTIL the "return True" line occurs, so doing this time.sleep(10) will do it so the music will play only for 10 seconds.

My question is:
How can I make this play function without making the music stop whenever the function returns?

**Edit**:

I made is so the function will return True or False so that the superclass that manages all the commands will know whether each command ran successfully or not

**Note**

This is just a small portion of the code that is relevant to this question. If you suspect there's more to see in the code to understand my problem please write it in the comments :)

Comment: It would be important to know what happens after the return in the program execution. Have you e. g. tried to add another "sleep" directly after the call to the function which contains the shown code?

Comment: Ok I tried doing sleep after, and it did work, but I have no idea what else would cut it, because the only line that comes after this function is called is a print to print the result of the function (True or False) and afterwards the function that called the function ends


**Edit:**:


Even if I put the sleep after the print I still hear the sound, it seems like it stops after the other function returns, which is a problem itself

Comment: Ok, so I traced back to the first place it is called, and it goes through some functions, and I used sleep there, and it worked too, seems like it stopped because the program stopped... I feel kinda dumb right now lol, Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the winsound didn't stop because of the function, it stopped because the program ended, my mistake.. :)
sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
pip install playsound
```

code

```
from playsound import playsound

def sound():
    playsound('test.mp3')

sound()
```

Comment: I tried playsound before, the reason it didn't work is that it threw me an error saying I need to choose a drive address shorter than 79 characters which I couldn't because the music was not in the python Folder but in a different once somewhere on my PC.

But I already solved my problem, the program just ended so it stopped the music, it was my bad. But thanks so much for commenting anyways :)